# Dynamically updating rolling sum

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with initial allowance and costs of some items. I want to get if I can afford the product with my budget given that I buy all products before which I can.

Here is an reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE budget
(     id int,
      alowance float64,
      cost float64,     
);

INSERT INTO budget (id, alowance, cost)
VALUES (1, 5000.0, 290.6),
     (2, 5000.0, 3915.26),
     (3, 5000.0, 3831.13),
     (4, 5000.0, 957.78)
;
```

I have used the lag of the rolling sum. However, I am struggling to update the last row as the second to last row transaction is not executed, so I have still some allowance left.

Here's my code:

```
with roll_sum as (
select *,
 sum(cost) over (order by id) as running_sum,
from budget
)
select *,
    coalesce(lag(running_sum) over (order by id), 0) as lag_running_sum,
    alowance - coalesce(lag(running_sum) over (order by id), 0) as current_limit
from roll_sum 
order by id
```

Attached is a screenshot of what I am getting and what I am looking for - the column true_current_limit with correct last value and decision if I can buy it or not.

[image]

Comment: tag your database

Comment: What makes you think that `794.14` is the "correct" value? Based on your description, the "correct" value is your allowance (`5000`) minus the previous running total (`8036.99`). How can a positive number be the "correct" answer to subtracting a larger number from a smaller number?

Comment: Are you looking to subtract the running sum from *two* rows before the current row instead?

Comment: This is what I mean here:
`I want to get if I can afford the product with my budget given that I buy all products before which I can.`
The assumption is I buy all products if I can. For example, I spent 290.6, then for the second transaction the allowance left is 5000-290.6=4709.4, etc.
The third transaction I need to compare 3831.13 with 791.14, I can't buy it so, for the fourth I still have 794.14 left, which I compare 957.78 to

Comment: I wonder if you should not split your calculation : in the second step, look for lag running sum (eg `coalesce(lag(running_sum) over (order by id), 0)`) then add a third step to calculate your current limit